# What wavy italic font is this

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I've tried using http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ but to no avail. Does anyone know what font the text "Wholesome & Earth-Friendly" is? This is from the Farmer's Market Volusion Template (http://farmersmarket-demo.volusion.com/).

[image]

Comment: I'm also interested in the font of the small text below it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Sarah Script from LetterheadFonts.com](http://www.letterheadfonts.com/fonts/sarahscript.php)**

[image: script]